# Can anyone please explain me the following unix script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh

I recently had to debug some old scripts and struck at this code. Please explain me what the `awk` is doing here.

```
#!/bin/ksh
set -x on
ls -1 ../Rejectfiles/*.csv 2>/dev/null | while read file
do
    filename=${file##*/}
    if [ -f ../Processed/$filename ]
       then 
       awk '{ if (NR > 1){ print $0;}}' $file >> ../Processed/$filename
    else
       cp $file ../Processed/
   fi
done
```

Comment: Just note: the above script will work only if the filenames doesn't contains space or other special characters...

Comment: `tail -n +2` would be simpler than that `awk` invocation, and probably a bit more obvious to the casual reader, as well...

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{ if (NR > 1){ print $0;}}' $file >> ../Processed/$filename
```

Write all lines from `$file` without 1 line to `../Processed/$filename`

```
man awk | grep -i " NR  "
              NR        current record number in the total input stream.
```

also you can use sed

```
sed -n '1!p' $file >> ../Processed/$filename
```

Usually `sed` is more fast.

Comment: Simpler sed command (with properly quoted parameters): `sed 1d "$file" >>"../Processed/$filename"`

Answer (score 0):

`man awk` states clearly:

> **NR** - ordinal number of the current record

As @Sundeep noted in the comments of @RichardS his answer:

`awk '{ if (NR > 1){ print $0;}}' $file` thus removes the first ordinal number from the file. Given the input file is a CSV file the first ordinal number means the first line in the file. As @RichardS has mentioned that makes perfect sense in a CSV file (given the fact the first line in a CSV usually contains the description of the underlying values).